# What is the most time efficient way to solve this problem?

Tags: c++

We have five  different numbers. Write out the sum of the three biggest numbers. 1<=x<=10000
I tried writing if elses in if elses but that's not time efficient. After that I tried writing more statements in one if elses like if(a>b && b>c etc.) but that's really slow too, because I need to write a lot.

Comment: What do you mean with "time efficient"? The time it takes to write the code or the time it takes the code to execute?

Comment: You should post the code you have now. It's difficult to propose a faster solution if we don't know what you have so far.

Comment: Just use a bubble sort and take the 3 largest elements.  For 5 inputs bubble sort is basically perfect.

Comment: "...but that's really slow too" How did you measure that?

Answer (score 3):

1. Put the five numbers in an array
2. Sort this array in descending order, putting the highest number first
3. And finally just grab the first three numbers from your sorted array and sum them together.

Comment: 4. Use [`std::partial_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) to avoid sorting useless elements if you want to split hairs.

Comment: This approach may be fine as long as the array is small (OP asks for 5 elements only) but for a larger array the sorting will be too expensive.

Comment: @4386427 I fully agree! It's just that I figured pseudocode would be the best way to help out OP at the moment when he is still at this level. Start with the basics and grow from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
Manually order the first three to highest, middle, lowest
Compare the 4th with the lowest, and either
  discard 4th
or
  discard lowest
  compare with middle to select new lowest from 4th or middle

Compare 5th with new lowest, and either
  discard 5th
or 
  discard lowest

add up the 3 numbers
```

This saves 1 operation vs any sort algorithm when adding 4th number, where the 4th number is higher than the highest of the first 3 numbers, because the highest of the first 3 will never be discarded by the other 2.

It further saves against using a sort algorithm to insert the 5th number, but that would be obvious anyway.

Writing the Compare 5th clause 3 times in the first clause means slightly less data manipulation, but more code:

```
Compare the 4th with the lowest, and either
  (discard 4th)
  Compare 5th with lowest, and either
    add up 5th middle, highest
  or 
    add up lowest middle highest
or
  compare with middle to select new lowest from 4th or middle
    (4th)
    Compare 5th with 4th, and either
      add up 5th middle, highest
    or 
      add up 4th middle highest
 or
    Compare 5th with middle, and either
      add up 5th, 4th, highest
    or 
      add up 4th middle highest
```

Another option is to consider the two entries you are discarding, rather than the three entries you are keeping:

```
Order the first 2 entries to higher and lower 
If 3rd entry is lower than higher 
  If 3rd is lower than lower
    lower -> higher ; 3rd -> lower
  else
    3rd -> higher
If 4th entry is lower than higher 
  If 4th is lower than lower
    lower -> higher ; 4th -> lower
  else
    4th -> higher
If 5th entry is lower than higher 
  5th to higher
Sum all the entries except lower and higher, 
or sum /all/ the entries then subtract lower and higher
```

For larger numbers of entries to try, or to keep, the canonical approach is to maintain a heap with exactly the right number of elements to keep. When the next element is considered, compare it with the heap head, and if it is "better" then "revalue" the heap head and bubble it to its correct position. "Revalue/bubble head" is often not provided as a standard feature of heap management code, but is easy to implement, and is faster than deleting the old head and then inserting the new node.